# Is it possible to fetch multiple specific resources with JSON-API?

Tags: json-api

JSON-API [provides a way to fetch](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-resources) a collection of resources, or a single resource.

You can get a single resource and specify the inclusion of a relationship like so:

```
GET /articles/1?includes=author
```

Is it possible - according to the specification - to get, say, three specific articles in a single request?

Rather than:

```
GET /articles/1?includes=author
GET /articles/42?includes=author
GET /articles/67?includes=author
```

Do e.g. (this is made up for illustrative purposes):

```
GET /articles/1,42,67?includes=author
```

Comment: Please note that query param to specify inclusion of related resources should be `include` not `includes` [according to spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is although the spec is agnostic on the details. It does recommend the query parameter "filter" for that and has some [recommendations](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering). You would do this with get of a **collection** with a filter. Something like:

```
GET /articles?filter[id]=1,42,67&include=author
```